# Unable to start JBoss hosted programs from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jboss

I have a strange problem while trying to start JBoss from Eclipse.

After starting, I can deploy files on the server but on browsers (http://localhost:8080/...), the link appears broken.

But if I start JBoss from terminal, I can view it in browsers with the same url. And from port 8080 I can't start JBoss while no process is acquiring that port. SO i used port 8083. But the url http://localhost:8083 does not work too. (I am trying to deploy a web service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the port number to for example "80"

Comment: Thanx, changed it to 8083. Server started , and i can deploy files(.war, .ear etc). but i cant view them in browsers. The link is shown broken. for that i have to run jboss again from terminal

Comment: pehaps you have some sort of proxy issues.